# Custom format an inline formset

Tags: django, forms, formset

I'm create a template in Django, adding a form and formset to the template, but I don't like how it's formatting the formset by default.  I've tried .as_table and .as_ul, but it's not formatting it to my liking.  I'd like to see the following from the formset:

```
Ingredient   Percentage   Delete
ingredient1  .55
ingredient2  .22
ingredient3  .33
```

I've tried the code in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492374/how-to-render-formset-in-template-django-and-create-vertical-table" but when I implement it, I'm getting two extra column, "ID" and "Recipe Name".  I don't know where those columns are coming from and I don't know how to get rid of them.

Example:
[image: current_page]

models.py

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Recipe_Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe_name = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    recipe_percent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=5, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def recipeUpdate(request, recipe_id):
    RecipeIngredientFormSet2 = inlineformset_factory(Recipe, Recipe_Ingredient, extra=10, fields=('ingredient', 'recipe_percent'))
    recipe = Recipe.objects.get(pk=recipe_id)
    formset = RecipeIngredientFormSet2(instance=recipe)
    context = {'formset' : formset}
    return render(request, 'accounts/recipe_form.html', context)
```

recipe_form.html

```
{%  extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {{ form }}
                <p></p>
                <!--{{ formset.as_table }}-->
                <p></p>
                {{ formset.management_form}}
                <!--{% for form in formset %}
                    {{ form }}
                {% endfor %}-->
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        {% for form in formset %}
                            {% if forloop.first %}
                                {% for field in form %}
                                    <th>{{ field.label_tag }}</th>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                {% for field in form %}
                                    <td>{{ field }}</td>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <input type="submit" name="Submit">
            </form>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  You've got to add the formset with a .management_form tag, then in table, loop through each form in form set.  If it's the first loop, add the headers to the tables.  In all other loops, add each field from the form that you want in the table.
The updated HTML that I'm using is below.

```
{%  extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }}


                {{ formset.management_form }}

                <table>
                    {{ form.id }}
                    {% for p in formset %}
                        <tr>
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                            <td>{{ p.DELETE.label_tag }}</td>
                            <td>{{ p.ingredient.label_tag }}</td>
                            <td>{{ p.recipe_percent.label_tag }}</td>
                            <p></p>
                        {% endif %}
                        </tr>
                        <!--{{ p.id }}
                        {{ p.ORDER }}-->
                        <tr></tr>
                        <td>{{ p.DELETE }}</td>
                        <td>{{ p.ingredient }}</td>
                        <td>{{ p.recipe_percent }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>

                <input type="submit" name="Submit">
            </form>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).